# How to display content in Base URL of Jersey Web Application?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web, jersey

I want to ask the basic question about Jersey Application. 
**Is it possible to add and display HTML content in Base URL? If it is possible, how can I implement it?**

I use Jersey 2.X Application.
In the usual, I extends the ResourceConfig to implement and set the ApplicationPath as **"/api"**.
Besides, I set the resource Path as **"test"** in Test class and define testResp() with "GET" request.
I use maven to build **service.war** and deploy on local tomcat, so I can access http://localhost:8080/service/api/test to get result in browser.

But now, I want to display some HTML content in API Base URL: http://localhost:8080/service/api/
For example, I will put some introduction for this service and 
user can access API Base URL to read.
How can I implement it if possible? Thanks a lot!

Following is the some code example.

Jersey Application sample:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class WebApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public WebApplication() {
        /**
         * register resource, load setting, ...etc
         */
    }
}
```

Resource sample:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    public Response testResp() {
        /**
         * impliment the action of http://localhost:8080/service/api/test/
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a resource class annotated with `@Path("/")` or `@Path("")` then create a resource method to handle `GET` requests producing HTML:

```java
@Path("/")
public class WelcomeResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response produceHTML() {
        String html = "<p>Hello, World!</p>";
        return Response.ok(html).build();
    }
}
```

The HTML content will be available at `/api`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use this method to implement.

Comment: @Ringing.Wang I usually don't like `@Path` values defined as empty strings or just slashes, but it will do the trick in this situation.